# Using fancybox-media with fancybox-thumbs

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox, thumbnails, fancybox-2

I'm trying to create a (combined) image and YouTube video gallery using Fancybox while also utilizing Fancybox thumbs. I've run into two problems:

- When you click on the link for the video (the first link - PS, I'm not trying to Rick Roll you when you click on it lol), it opens up, but it doesn't show the thumbs or let you navigate through the other items in the group
- If you click on a link for an image (the second or third link), it shows all of the thumbnails that were generate - including a thumbnail for the video… but when you click on the thumbnail for the video, it doesn't skip to the video.

Thoughts?

```
$('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
    prevEffect: 'none',
    nextEffect: 'none',
    closeBtn  : true,
    arrows    : true,
    nextClick : true,
    helpers   : {thumbs: {width: 50, height: 50}}
});

$('.fancybox-media')
    .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
    .fancybox({
        openEffect : 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        prevEffect : 'none',
        nextEffect : 'none',
        arrows     : true,
        helpers    : {media: {}, buttons: {}}
});
```

Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/6j7wxr8e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First notice all elements of a fancybox gallery must share both, the same *selector* AND the same `rel` attribute (or the same `data-fancybox-group` attribute)

In your example, the selectors `.fancybox-thumbs` and `.fancybox-media` cannot belong to the same gallery regardless they share the same `rel` attribute. This also applies to elements sharing the same *selector* but with different `rel` attribute value. does it make sense?

So make sure your elements share the same *selector* like

```
<a class="fancybox">
<a class="fancybox">
<a class="fancybox">
```

You may not need to hard-code the `rel` attribute since you could initialize fancybox like :

```
$('.fancybox').attr('rel', 'media-gallery').fancybox();
```

... which sets the same `rel` attribute (`media-gallery`) to all elements with *class* `fancybox`.

Then you could group all your API options in a single initialization script, including fancybox helpers media, thumbs, buttons etc. like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.fancybox').attr('rel', 'media-gallery').fancybox({
        prevEffect: 'none',
        nextEffect: 'none',
        closeBtn: true,
        arrows: true,
        nextClick: true,
        helpers: {
            thumbs: {
                width: 50,
                height: 50
            }, // requires to include thumbs js and css files
            media: {}, // requires to include media js file
            buttons: {} // requires to include buttons js and css files
        }
    });
});
```

See your forked **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6j7wxr8e/2/)**

Comment: You're awesome! I noticed that they shared some of the same API options and tried to consolidate them - which kept breaking it. (I was obviously doing it wrong.) I still had to hard-code the rel attribute because of the nature of the project I'm working on, but that was an easy fix. Thank you so much!